# Why are margins unequal?

Tags: margins

I have set them this way:

```
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
```

But the left margin is bigger than the other (which are equal as should be).

Whats the problem?

EDIT:

I compile this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{anysize}
\begin{document}
3 $\hspace{150mm}$ 3 3 3
\end{document}
```

And print it. On paper now i see clearly bigger left margin than right.

Comment: Full minimal example please. And how exactly are you measuring that the margins are uneven?

Comment: What paper are you using? A4 or Letter?

Comment: @daleif I'm talking about the distance between the text and the edges of the paper.

Comment: @egreg I added a code now

Comment: Use the `geometry` package with option showframe, and you'll see the distance on screen is exactly 1 in. So the problem comes from your printer configuration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the `anysize` package, it is messing something up.

Also a better way of testing might be to use

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
%\usepackage{anysize}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\rule{\textwidth}{3mm}

\end{document}
```

Just had a look at `anysize`, it is from 1994!!! Drop it. Basically, `geometry` sets the margins, and `anysize` resets them, thus your reported problem.

Comment: 1994? quite new then compared to most of my packages

Comment: Well, most of your packages have stood the test of time. Some are just legacy stuff that new users should not be using ;-)